# How to place text at the end of a caption?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, captions

I would like to put the text with copyright issue of an image currently in the List of Figures, but maybe I have to change it and place it (also) below of each image.

This MWE works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\after[1]{#1}
\newcommand\afterlof{; \after}
\newcommand\aftercap{ }%for optional use
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\def\after{the copyright for this image}
    \caption%
     [caption for LOF\afterlof]%
     {caption below the image\aftercap}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\def\after{the copyright for another image}
    \caption%
     [caption for LOF\afterlof]%
     {caption below the image\aftercap}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

My question:

> Is there a way *not* to put the two commands (`afterlof` and `aftercap`) in each caption manually?
>   So that by definition the caption always looks like `\caption[  \afterlof]{   \aftercap}`?

Comment: It should be possible with a special caption format

Comment: It's not quite clear to me: do you want the copyright to be both in the list of figures, and with the figure itself?

Comment: A key-value - syntax would be better, in my point of view. Unfortunately, the `caption` package does not have `hooks` etc. to place additional content/code (or I did not find it :-()

Comment: @Bernard I would like to be flexible, defining it globally to be only in the list of figures or/and additionally with the figure itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose a key-value interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xcaption}{O{}m}
 {% #1 are options, #2 is the main caption text
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lukascb_caption_text_tl { #2 }
  \keys_set:nn { lukascb/caption }
   {
    loftext = #2,
    #1
   }
  \lukascb_make_caption:VVVV
    \l_lukascb_caption_text_tl
    \l_lukascb_caption_aftercap_tl
    \l_lukascb_caption_loftext_tl
    \l_lukascb_caption_afterlof_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l_lukascb_caption_text_tl

\keys_define:nn { lukascb/caption }
 {
  loftext  .tl_set:N = \l_lukascb_caption_loftext_tl,
  afterlof .tl_set:N = \l_lukascb_caption_afterlof_tl,
  aftercap .tl_set:N = \l_lukascb_caption_aftercap_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lukascb_make_caption:nnnn
 {
  \caption
    [ #3 \tl_if_empty:nF { #4 } { ;~#4 } ]
    { #1 \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 } { ;~#2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \lukascb_make_caption:nnnn { VVVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Main text}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\xcaption[
  loftext=caption for LOF,
  afterlof=copyright for this image,
]{caption below the image}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\xcaption[
  afterlof=the copyright,
  aftercap=something else,
]{caption below the image}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you don't specify `loftext`, the main caption text is used. The value of `afterlof` is appended in the list of figures, the value of `aftercap` to the main caption.

Thus you have only to add the keys if you want to use them.

[image]

An extension for `\subcaptionbox`, the syntax is similar: the first optional argument to `\subcaptionbox` becomes a list of options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xparse}

\captionsetup[sub]{list=true}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xcaption}{O{}m}
 {% #1 are options, #2 is the main caption text
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lukascb_caption_text_tl { #2 }
  \lukascb_make_caption:Nnn \__lukascb_make_caption:VVVV { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\xsubcaptionbox}{O{}m}
 {% #1 are options, #2 is the main caption text
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lukascb_caption_text_tl { #2 }
  \lukascb_make_caption:Nnn \__lukascb_make_subcaption:VVVV { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lukascb_make_caption:Nnn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { lukascb/caption }
   {% first clear the variables
    loftext = #3,
    aftercap = {},
    afterlof = {},
    % then load the given ones
    #2
   }
  #1 \l_lukascb_caption_text_tl \l_lukascb_caption_aftercap_tl
     \l_lukascb_caption_loftext_tl \l_lukascb_caption_afterlof_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l_lukascb_caption_text_tl

\keys_define:nn { lukascb/caption }
 {
  loftext  .tl_set:N = \l_lukascb_caption_loftext_tl,
  afterlof .tl_set:N = \l_lukascb_caption_afterlof_tl,
  aftercap .tl_set:N = \l_lukascb_caption_aftercap_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lukascb_make_caption:nnnn
 {
  \caption
    [ #3 \tl_if_empty:nF { #4 } { ;~#4 } ]
    { #1 \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 } { ;~#2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__lukascb_make_caption:nnnn { VVVV }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lukascb_make_subcaption:nnnn
 {
  \subcaptionbox
    [ #3 \tl_if_empty:nF { #4 } { ;~#4 } ]
    { #1 \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 } { ;~#2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__lukascb_make_subcaption:nnnn { VVVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Main text}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\xcaption[
  loftext=caption for LOF,
  afterlof=copyright for this image,
]{caption below the image}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\xsubcaptionbox[
  afterlof=the copyright A,
  aftercap=something else,
]{subcaption}{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\qquad
\xsubcaptionbox[
  afterlof=the copyright B,
]{subcaption}{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

\xcaption[
  afterlof=the copyright,
]{caption below the image}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your idea with `loftext`, but how can I make it work with the package `subcaption` and `subcaptionbox[text for lof]{text for caption}{\includegraphics....}` as well? That would be great!

Comment: @LukasCB Added also `\xsubcaptionbox`

Comment: great. but it seems like some sort of `undef` after each `afterlof` etc. is necessary. Otherwise the text from `afterlof` will also be printed in another subfigure/subcaption or even caption.

Comment: @LukasCB You're right: fixed.

Answer (score 2):

A quick 'hack' by a redefinition of `\caption` with `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand` and testing whether `\after` etc. is defined.

Use `\def\after{...}` or `\newcommand{\after}` inside of the figure environment, as such, that the command is not defined outside and the test will do the `false` branch, don't printing additional text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\let\caption@@caption\caption
\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{so+m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \caption@@caption*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \caption@@caption[#2\@ifundefined{after}{}{\afterlof}]{#3~\@ifundefined{after}{}{\aftercap}}%
    }{%
      \caption@@caption{#3~\csname aftercap\endcsname}
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatother

\newcommand\afterlof{; \after}
\newcommand\aftercap{ }%for optional use
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \def\after{the copyright for this image}
    \caption[caption for LOF]{caption below the image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \def\after{Another copyright for another image}
    \def\aftercap{Some info}
    \caption[caption for LOF]{Normal caption below the image}

    \caption{Another caption below the image}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternate version with key-value syntax, please note the 2nd optional argument of the `\caption` argument!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{caption}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_lukascb_caption_prop 

\keys_define:nn {lukascb} {%
  afterlof .code:n={\prop_put:Nnn \l_lukascb_caption_prop {afterlof} {#1}},
  aftercap .code:n={\prop_put:Nnn \l_lukascb_caption_prop {aftercap} {#1}},
  afterlofsep .code:n={\prop_put:Nnn \l_lukascb_caption_prop {afterlofsep} {#1}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SetLocalCaptionOptions}{m}{%
  \prop_clear:N \l_lukascb_caption_prop 
  \keys_set:nn {lukascb} {afterlofsep={;},#1}
}

\cs_new:Npn \retrievecaptiondata #1{%
  \prop_item:Nn \l_lukascb_caption_prop {#1}%
}


% Normally a `\prg_new_conditional, but for quickness much shorter..

\cs_new:Npn \ifcaptiondatagiven #1#2#3{%
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \l_lukascb_caption_prop {#1} {%
    #2%
  }{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\makeatletter
\let\caption@@caption\caption
\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{so+mO{}}{%
  \SetLocalCaptionOptions{#4}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \caption@@caption*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \caption@@caption[#2\ifcaptiondatagiven{afterlof}{\retrievecaptiondata{afterlofsep}\retrievecaptiondata{afterlof}}{}]{#3~\retrievecaptiondata{aftercap}}%
    }{%
      \caption@@caption{#3~\retrievecaptiondata{aftercap}}
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption[First caption for LOF]{caption below the image}[afterlof={\textcopyright\ By me!}, aftercap={And now for something completely different}]
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption[caption for LOF]{Normal caption below the image}[afterlofsep={\S}]

    \caption{Another caption below the image}[aftercap={Nudge nudge}]
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution. I like the "quick and dirty" one, but couldnt make it work for `subcaption` (I know I didnt ask for it in first place).

Comment: @LukasCB: Yes, you didn't ask about that and accepted a solution that provided it after you pushed it ;-)