# How to get different values for chapter/section/etc, head and TOC?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, koma-script

I would like to give different values to headline, head and TOC.
In the MWE I have chosen `subsection` but there might be the possibility to make it work for `chapter`, `section` etc.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark*[subsection]{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My Chapter}\clearpage
\section{My Section}\clearpage
\subsection[%
  head={My Subsection in the Header},
  totoc={My Subsection in the TOC}]{My Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

There might be a similar solution as described here: [How to place text at the end of a caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364710/98739) ?

Comment: With a KOMA-Script class you have to enable the advanced functionality of the optional argument: Set one of the options `headings=optiontoheadandtoc`,  `headings=optiontohead` or `headings=optiontotoc`.

Comment: I get `Package keyval Error: totoc undefined.` then using `headings=optiontoheadandtoc`.

Comment: Replace `totoc=...` by `tocentry=...`.

Comment: :-( That was easier than expected. it works like charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the used KOMA-Script class you only have to enable the advanced functionality of the optional argument of the sectioning commands: set one of the  KOMA-Script options `headings=optiontoheadandtoc`, `headings=optiontohead` or `headings=optiontotoc`.

Then you can set different values for `head` and `tocentry` in the optional argument to get different entries for header and ToC.

Example

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc% <- added
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark*[subsection]{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My Chapter}\clearpage
\section{My Section}\clearpage
\subsection[%
  head={My Subsection in the Header},
  tocentry={My Subsection in the TOC}]{My Subsection}% <- changed: tocentry
\clearpage
Text
\clearpage
\subsection[Second Subsection in Header and TOC]{Second Subsection}
\end{document}
```